# Comment length is not validated until the close vote is submitted

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, validation, custom-close-reasons

When I try to add a one character long comment to a question the "Add Comment" button will do nothing (because validation fails) - that okay. Yet if I

1. click "Close" on a question,
2. select "offtopic because", then
3. select "other", then
4. delete all the text and type a one character long comment and then
5. click "Vote to close"

the button works but I then see a red bar with a message saying that my comment should have been at least 30 characters long.

It looks like client-side validation doesn't work in case of close-voting.

Comment: Same for me too when attempting to close this question (as a test). The correct behaviour is clearly possible as the suggested edit reject-->other works nicely

Answer (score -1):

This has been fixed and it was due to a shoddy check in JavaScript. I've also made the placeholder text a ...real `placeholder`.

It will be deployed in the next build out.

Comment: Great, however the fix looks not yet deployed.

Comment: @sharptooth edited.

Comment: That text was not supposed to be a `placeholder`! It's a default start, and it's useful. Please bring it back!

Comment: (Or better, get rid of custom close reasons and bring back the generic off-topic.)